# Is it recommended to redeclare abstract methods in inheriting abstract class if not implemented?

Tags: java

Is it good practice to redeclare abstract methods in inheriting abstract class if it doesn't implement it? 
e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractBase {
    abstract void method1();
    abstract void method2();
    ..
}

abstract class AbstractPartialImpl extends AbstractBase {
    void method1() {...}
    abstract void method2();     // SHOULD I KEEP THIS?
    protected abstract void method3();
    ...
}

class FullImpl extends AbstractPartialImpl  {
    void method2() {...}
    protected void method3() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it good practice to redeclare abstract methods in inheriting abstract class if it doesn't implement it?

This question is subjective, as are most issues of style.

However here are some specific cases where it is an objectively useful thing to do:

- You can redeclare the method to increase its visibility; e.g. package private -> protected -> public.
- You can redeclare the method to throw a smaller set of exceptions.
- You can redeclare the method to return a subtype of the original type.
- You can redeclare the method so that you can add more specific javadocs.

---

Subjectively ... if none of the above applied, I would say that the redeclaration adds no value, and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against it, because if you ever decide to change the API at the top, now you have to remember to change it all the way down the hierarchy - otherwise you could now have ...

```
abstract void method2(String arg);
```

... as well as ...

```
abstract void method();
```

both defined.  Because of this, defining it all the way down the hierarchy as abstract is not recommended.

Basically, it's giving you more code to maintain while not giving you any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with it as as you said *"it doesn't implement it"*.

Remember that a class can only `extends` one class.

Also remember that `implements` is not the same as `extends`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any point in redeclaring an abstract method that you're not going to implement, unless possibly for the purpose of attaching documentation to it of details demanded of extensions of that abstract subclass.  Even that is a bow to the limitations of the tools, and not often needed.  Were you working for me, yes, I'd probably have you remove `AbstractPartialImplementation.method2()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I couldn't find any guidelines in Java API or other specs. So I am wondering what is the practice in general. Thanks for your input.